# Select listbox item if contain a string in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to select listbox item if contains a specific string. Here is my code:

```
string SearchDomain="youdial.in";
for (int i = 0; i < ListBox2.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                var UrlList = new Uri(ListBox2.Items[i].ToString());
                var UrlList = UrlList.Host;
                if (UrlList == SearchDomain)
                {
                    ListBox2.SelectedIndex = i;
                    urllbl.Text = ListBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    return;
                }
            }
```

[image]

If ListBox2 have more than 1 matched results than above code select last matched item, but i want to select first matched item. e.g if Query match with 3rd, 7th and 9th item, I want to get the value of 3rd item. Thanks in Advance, sorry for my bad English.

Comment: As an aside, this code will throw an exception if there is no matching element as you're doing `i <= ListBox2.Items.Count`. you're lucky it didn't do so before. you're looking for `i < ListBox2.Items.Count`

Comment: as for _"If ListBox2 have more than 1 matched results than above code select last matched item"_ . I don't see how that's possible as you're iterating sequentially from the first index to the last.

Comment: Again, your code doesn't even compile as you cannot compare a type `URI` and a `string` like this --> `if (UrlList == SearchDomain)`.

Comment: #Aomine I don't know how is this possible, My question updated with output image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change return; to break; Break statement will stop the for loop from executing further.

```
string SearchDomain="youdial.in";
for (int i = 0; i < ListBox2.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                var UrlList = new Uri(ListBox2.Items[i].ToString());
                var UrlList = UrlList.Host;
                if (UrlList == SearchDomain)
                {
                    ListBox2.SelectedIndex = i;
                    urllbl.Text = ListBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just reverse the counter change the

`for (int i = 0; i < ListBox2.Items.Count; i++)`

to

`for (int i = ListBox2.Count-1 ; i > -1 ; i--)`